# How can I parse the given JSON data in objective c and show in table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsarray

I have two array.  Say `A` for section and inside it array `B` for  rows.  How can I access them to show `numberOfRowsInSection` and also the rows regarding section to show in cell.

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "data": {
        "claims": [{
            "id": "64",
                "first_name": "Alia",
                "last_name": "Bhatt",
                "vendorimage": "http://projects.kleward.com/salesaward/beta1.5/public/profileImage/img1445325413.jpeg",
                "claimlist": [{
                "campaign_end_date": "2016-10-31",
                    "days": "362",
                    "promotion_id": "7",
                    "promotion_name": "Promotion 1 Jeans",
                    "promotion_description": " Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Description  Promotion Descripti",
                    "totalClaim": "1",
                    "totatAmount": "200.00000"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "65",
                "first_name": "Life",
                "last_name": "Style",
                "vendorimage": "http://projects.kleward.com/salesaward/beta1.5/public/profileImage/img1445331248.jpg",
                "claimlist": [{
                "campaign_end_date": "2016-11-23",
                    "days": "385",
                    "promotion_id": "9",
                    "promotion_name": "Promotion 3 Wrist Watch",
                    "promotion_description": "Promotion 3 Wrist Watch Description",
                    "totalClaim": "1",
                    "totatAmount": "300.00000"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "76",
                "first_name": "Snap",
                "last_name": "Deal",
                "vendorimage": "http://projects.kleward.com/salesaward/beta1.5/public/profileImage/img1445851551.png",
                "claimlist": [{
                "campaign_end_date": "2016-12-29",
                    "days": "421",
                    "promotion_id": "10",
                    "promotion_name": "Dell Promotion",
                    "promotion_description": "Dell Promotion Description",
                    "totalClaim": "1",
                    "totatAmount": "50.00000"
            }, {
                "campaign_end_date": "2016-12-30",
                    "days": "422",
                    "promotion_id": "16",
                    "promotion_name": "Mac Promotion",
                    "promotion_description": "Mac Promotion Description",
                    "totalClaim": "1",
                    "totatAmount": "150.00000"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with NSJSONSerialization, then write code. That's what everyone else does.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray *sectionArray = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"claims"];
    NSInteger sectionAmount = [sectionArray count];

    for(NSDictionary *detailDict in sectionArray){
      NSInteger detailID = [[detailDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
      NSString *firstName = [detailDict objectForKey:@"first_name"];

      //And so on, do stuff here with each detail
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsed JSon in following structure

- Maintains NSArray containing rows count for each section.
- Maintains NSDictionary containing array for each section like Section as Key and Array as value.

Table Decoratio

- Initialise an array with capacity Array A count and save rows count for each section. To decorate rows use section index to get count of rows in method "Number of rows in section"
- Get array from NSDictionary passing section index to decorate rows in section.

Answer (score 0):

As i got `Section` in your `JSON` sample is `claims` and objects in `claims` are `rows`. If yes then every thing is simple:

JSON - is income Data

```
NSDictionary * dict = [JSON objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Get the Sections to use in numberOfSection

```
NSArray * sectionTitles = [dict allKeys];
```

Number of section

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return [sectionTitles count];
}
```

Number of rows in section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString * sectionTitle = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray * rows = [dict objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [rows count];
}
```

Row of current section for indexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // init Cell

    // Get Section Title from indexPath
    NSString * sectionTitle = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    // Get Array of object for Section
    NSArray * objects = [dict objectForKey:sectionTitle];

    // Get Object for row
    NSDictionary * object = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Use it
    NSString * objectID = [object objectForKey:@"id"];

   // return cell;
}
```

To show Section Header

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Comment: i think you forgot to return cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. and this code in app will be crash in titleForHeaderInSection method. Thanks.

Comment: @GanganiRoshan I had mentioned that you have to return the cell in comments `// return cell;` of course same as mentioned that you have to init cell `// init Cell` but thanks for comment